# "Failed to open stream: Permission denied" Connecting bitcoind with JSON-RPC PHP

Tags: php, json, apache, json-rpc, bitcoind

I'm trying to control bitcoin daemon with PHP but I am having an issue when trying to connect to it.

I've followed these steps: en.bitcoin (dot) it/wiki/PHP_developer_intro

PHP code:

```
<?php
require_once 'jsonRPCClient.php';
$bitcoin = new jsonRPCClient('http://user:password@127.0.0.1:8332/');
echo "<pre>\n";
print_r($bitcoin->getinfo());
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Bitcoind conf:

```
rpcuser=user
rpcpassword=password
server=1
daemon=1
listen=1
```

var/log/httpd/error_log:

> **[Tue Apr 06 15:47:15.403045 2015] [:error] [pid 2293] [client 10.0.0.34:50333] PHP Warning:  fopen(http://...@127.0.0.1:8332/): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/jsonRPCClient.php on line 132 [Tue Apr 06 15:47:15.410993 2015] [:error] [pid 2293] [client 10.0.0.34:50333] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to connect to http://user:password@127.0.0.1:8332/' in /var/www/html/jsonRPCClient.php:140\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/bitcoin_get_info.php(15): jsonRPCClient->__call('getinfo', Array)\n#1 /var/www/html/bitcoin_get_info.php(15): jsonRPCClient->getinfo()\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/jsonRPCClient.php on line 1406**

Edit:

```
$ bitcoin-cli getinfo
```

Works fine, with PHP it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding `rpcallowip=127.0.0.1` into your config and see what happens.

Also make sure that your `bitcoind.conf` is actually being used, to test this you can set the daemon to testnet using `testnet=1` in `bitcoind.conf`.  Restart your bitcoind server then do `bitcoin-cli getinfo` to see which network it's connected to.  If the change isn't reflected then perhaps the `bitcoind.conf` file is in another location?

Also, make sure you restart your bitcoind server every time you make a change to the `bitcoind.conf` file.